# Sabre Session Token Expiring

Tags: php, sabre

I have retrieved the session token using `SessionCreateRQ`, I know the session token expires after 15 minutes, how do i use `OTA_PingRQ` to update my session, there is no proper payload for that action, so please if any can give the SOAP payload.

Comment: I guess you have to re create the session with the returned values in the first call of SessionCreateRQ

Comment: should i call again SessionCreateRQ to retrived new session token?

Comment: someone suggested using OTA_PingRQ in similar question to update session, i can not find the proper payload for SOAP request.

Answer (score 2):

No need to have a payload other than what you have below

```
<OTA_PingRQ TimeStamp="2018-04-28T15:15:00-06:00" Version="1.0.0">
  <EchoData>FREE TEXT</EchoData>
</OTA_PingRQ>
```

Complete request with envelope:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
            <eb:ConversationId/>
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId>{FROM}</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId>{TO}</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>{IPCC}</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML">OTA_PingRQ</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>OTA_PingRQ</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>{MESSAGEID}</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>{TIMESTAMP}</eb:Timestamp>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>{TOKEN}</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <OTA_PingRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" Version="1.0.0">
            <EchoData> Are you there </EchoData>
        </OTA_PingRQ>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: According to the documentation this requires token, it is not clear to me that where should i pass my old token to this request.

Comment: i was trying to do this way, if you could guide me to the right way,

 `<wsse:Security
            xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTC!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3151269852736338038!1424538!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    
</soap-env:Header>
<soap-env:Body>
<OTA_PingRQ TimeStamp="2011-02-28T15:15:00-06:00" Version="1.0.0">
<EchoData> Are you there </EchoData>
</OTA_PingRQ>
</soap-env:Body>`

Comment: The token goes where you've put it, yes. Are you getting an error on that?

Comment: Added a full request example, in case that is what troubles you

Answer (score 2):

When you use SessionCreateRQ request  the first time you store the returned BinarySecurityToken from the SessionCreateRS response. 
Use this BinarySecurityToken in the OTA_PingRQ request. 
Here is an example of OTA_PingRQ request with Soap Envelope:

```
 <soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
  <soap-env:header>
    <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" soap-env:mustUnderstand="0">
      <eb:From>
        <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">from</eb:PartyId>
      </eb:From>
      <eb:To>
        <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">ws</eb:PartyId>
      </eb:To>
      <eb:CPAId>[CPA_ID]</eb:CPAId>
      <eb:ConversationId>[CONVERSATION_ID]</eb:ConversationId>
      <eb:Service>OTA_PingRQ</eb:Service>
      <eb:Action>OTA_PingRQ</eb:Action>
      <eb:MessageData>
        <eb:MessageId>[MESSAGE_ID]</eb:MessageId>
        <eb:Timestamp>[TIMESTAMP]</eb:Timestamp>
      </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <eb:Security xmlns:eb="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" soap-env:mustUnderstand="0">
      <eb:BinarySecurityToken>[BINARY_SECURITY_TOKEN]</eb:BinarySecurityToken>
    </eb:Security>
  </soap-env:header>
  <soap-env:Body>
    <OTA_PingRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" TimeStamp="2011-02-28T15:15:00-06:00" Version="1.0.0">
      <EchoData>Are you there</EchoData>
    </OTA_PingRQ>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```